Task did not complete: LocalConversionTask

What caused this?   Linux systeam.


I try to modify file's permissons;
And I am sure This systeam space is sufficent.

And I try to restart LibbaryOffice,But useless.

org.jodconverter.core.office.OfficeException: Task did not complete: LocalConversionTask{source=SourceDocumentSpecsFromInputStream{file=null, format=docx}, loadProperties=null, target=TargetDocumentSpecsFromOutputStream{file=null, format=pdf}, storeProperties=null}
        at org.jodconverter.core.office.AbstractOfficeManagerPoolEntry.execute(AbstractOfficeManagerPoolEntry.java:104) ~[jodconverter-core-4.4.2.jar!/:4.4.2]
        at org.jodconverter.core.office.AbstractOfficeManagerPool.execute(AbstractOfficeManagerPool.java:217) ~[jodconverter-core-4.4.2.jar!/:4.4.2]
        at org.jodconverter.local.LocalConverter$LocalConversionJob.doExecute(LocalConverter.java:149) ~[jodconverter-local-4.4.2.jar!/:4.4.2]
        at org.jodconverter.core.job.AbstractConversionJob.execute(AbstractConversionJob.java:62) ~[jodconverter-core-4.4.2.jar!/:4.4.2]
        at com.frame.szda.file.application.service.fileprocess.fileconvert.FileConvertToPdfComponent.generateNoWatermarkPdf(FileConvertToPdfComponent.java:293) [classes!/:3.0.1]
        at com.frame.szda.file.application.service.fileprocess.fileconvert.FileConvertToPdfComponent.processFile(FileConvertToPdfComponent.java:198) [classes!/:3.0.1]
        at com.frame.szda.mq.application.event.subscribe.LargeFileConvertPdfMqReceiver.consumerMsg(LargeFileConvertPdfMqReceiver.java:76) [classes!/:3.0.1]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor587.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_382]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_382]
        at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:171) [spring-messaging-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:120) [spring-messaging-5.2.14.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.14.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:53) [spring-rabbit-2.2.16.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:222) [spring-rabbit-2.2.16.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandlerAndProcessResult(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:150) [spring-rabbit-2.2.16.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:135) [spring-rabbit-2.2.16.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1608) [spring-rabbit-2.2.16.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1527) [spring-rabbit-2.2.16.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1515) [spring-rabbit-2.2.16.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1506) [spring-rabbit-2.2.16.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1450) [spring-rabbit-2.2.16.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer$SimpleConsumer.callExecuteListener(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:1073) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.16.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer$SimpleConsumer.handleDelivery(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:1033) ~[spring-rabbit-2.2.16.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.16.RELEASE]
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerDispatcher$5.run(ConsumerDispatcher.java:149) ~[amqp-client-5.9.0.jar!/:5.9.0]
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerWorkService$WorkPoolRunnable.run(ConsumerWorkService.java:104) ~[amqp-client-5.9.0.jar!/:5.9.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_382]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_382]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) ~[na:1.8.0_382]
Caused by: org.jodconverter.core.job.DocumentSpecsIOException: Could not write stream to file '/tmp/.jodconverter_b1904072-c94c-439f-b3e5-615936270d07/tempfile_122.docx'
        at org.jodconverter.core.job.SourceDocumentSpecsFromInputStream.getFile(SourceDocumentSpecsFromInputStream.java:83) ~[jodconverter-core-4.4.2.jar!/:4.4.2]
        at org.jodconverter.local.task.LocalConversionTask.execute(LocalConversionTask.java:108) ~[jodconverter-local-4.4.2.jar!/:4.4.2]
        at org.jodconverter.local.office.LocalOfficeManagerPoolEntry.doExecute(LocalOfficeManagerPoolEntry.java:120) ~[jodconverter-local-4.4.2.jar!/:4.4.2]
        at org.jodconverter.core.office.AbstractOfficeManagerPoolEntry.lambda$execute$0(AbstractOfficeManagerPoolEntry.java:80) ~[jodconverter-core-4.4.2.jar!/:4.4.2]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_382]
        ... 3 common frames omitted


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

https://github.com/jodconverter/jodconverter/issues/220 <- do you have something that is cleaning /tmp periodically?

Is "systeam" some specific software product or do you mean system?

What is "LibbaryOffice"? and why the empty bullet points?
